# Want to create a link I can send people that will open their email app with a pre-written message (NOT A LINK ON MY OWN WEBPAGE OR APP)

Tags: html, ios, url

I am trying to replicate something someone has done in this link https://l.instagram.com/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2Fyd49a4ow&e=ATMn3WfYRw5VZzFDz9FU9Pp0jqk5uBpX0Vo4n2MffH-mr8W5f84IEmpo-Rbx3neyIU0ehQcntNJuRsSGfW9bjw&s=1.
When on a mobile app the link opens the mail app with a pre-written email body subject and recipients. 
It is similar to the mailto function if I were designing my own web page and using HTML but this is a link I want to be able to email and share with people.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: The link you have shared is broken. It's always best to share the link and the screen shot. Also try to provide code you have already tried if any.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `mailto` links: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/

The long-and-short of it is that you can make a link that looks like this:

```html
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?subject=Big%20News&body=Body-goes-here">Email Us</a>
```

Basically, you are using the link's query parameters to preset the subject line, recipient, and body of the email.

Build your link like so:

`mailto:<the *recipient's* email>?subject=<subject line>&body=<email content>`

Then you can add the following options:

- Carbon Copy (`cc`) and Blind Carbon Copy (`bcc`)

  - Each email must be separated by a comma (`&cc=email@example.com, email2@example.com`)
- Subject (`subject`)
- Email body text (`body`)

Make sure to URL-encode the subject and email body text as well.